# Unable to disable mongodb anonymus login

Tags: mongodb

i am running mongod from an administrator command prompt on windows 8 Pro 64bit using the following command `mongod -f "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.0\bin\mongod.cfg"` the mongod.cfg file is ad follows

```
dbpath=e:\data
port=27017
logpath = e:\data\log\mongod.log
auth=true
```

i have created a user in the **admin** but still when i use mongo i can **login without username and password** can anyone help me disable this annonymus login. Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you assigned roles to this user? Is the DB password protected?

Comment: i have created the user using `system.users.createUsers(..)` and provided the username and password and the role array

Comment: i have created the user in `admin` db...i have updated the question

Comment: can you make queries? or it returns an error? if auth is enabled, only users with assigned roles can acces mongo dbs using the defined roles. Try to post some output.

Comment: i can use `db.getUsers()` in the admin database when logged in using username and password but for anonymus login it returns not authorized error

Comment: If it returns error, that means you are not authenticated. You are just using the shell, but you do not have access to the DB, you are NOT loged in as annonymous.

Comment: ok...but i can still create db and collections when logged in anonymusly...i mean i cannot execute queries on the admin db but can create a new db and collections in it...can this be disabled

Comment: Are you sure you still can create db and collection? Attention, creating a db and a collection means to actually save a first document in that DB and colelction. Try to save a document in a new DB see if it throw an error.

Comment: no i cannot save a document...I just tried that...thanks for the explanation...but can the accesss to the mongo shell be restricted with a username and password??

Comment: I think not, and I think your configuration is OK.

Comment: ok thank you for the explanation..i am new to mongodb and this discussion really helped me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If configuration is correct You need to have `auth` enabled, and users defined with specific `roles`. That's it.

Users based on their roles can access MongoDB DBs, they  can make queries only after they are authenticated.

You can connect, but when you are not authorized is more an anonymous connection, not anonymous login, cause there is no authentication.

If you are not authenticated, than running queries will throw an error.

Comment: nothing specific. the anonymous default logic can access everything.